# Where should I ask a question about problems booting a computer and recovery?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I ask a question about problems booting a computer and recovery? Not really much to add, I can't boot my laptop and want some help since solutions I've found don't seem to work.

Comment: What operating system does your laptop have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fit for [Super User](http://superuser.com).

But "I can't boot my laptop" is going to be closed as "Too Broad". You will have to provide us with more information.

And you have more information than you think. The OS, the type of laptop, how long this has been going on, what changed before this started to happen...

Also, specify just what happens when you try to boot.

Tell us what you have tried to solve it, and how these attempts failed. For example, have you tried booting from an Ubuntu live CD/DVD? And what happened?

The more specific information you can provide, the better we should be able to help.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to be fast and short for the meta answer, I will provide much more information over there.